# How to simply display in image with ImageMagick?

Tags: c++, imagemagick, zbar

I have an Image created with ImageMagick. I'm working in C++:

```
int height = xxx;
int width = xxx;
uchar* raw = xxxx; // data from somewhere else
format = "Y800";
Image myImage(width, height, format, raw, width*height);
```

I just want to visualize the Image to the screen in a very simple way to make sure that the raw data was applied correctly. How can I do this?

[yes I've RTFM. All I can find is how to do it in shell if I want to display image file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confusing Zbar::Image with Magick::Image.

```
Zbar::Image myZbarImage(width, height, format, raw, width*height);
```

is the constructor for Zbar::Image which is not directly compatible with Magick::Image, which has its on constructors [manual](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html#Constructors). I can then easily display with the `display()` function:

```
Magick::Image myMagickImage; // fill
myMagickImage.display();
```